# Incorrect Parameter Usage

Tags: sql, powerbi, report

I seem to be using these parameters incorrect but I can't seem to find out why or how to use them correctly in my instance. I'm using the PowerBI Report Builder program to pull data from an ODBC connection using a query.

In my query, I'm trying to use parameters set by the user in my query. I thought this was possible using the dataset properties and setting their parameters to the query ones but I may be referencing them incorrectly.

My query is:

```
select stuff
from pub.transactions
inner join pub.parts on pub.transactions.part=pub.parts.part and pub.transactions.domain = pub.parts.domain
where (pub.transactions.date >= @StartDate and pub.transactions.date <= @EndDate)
```

The issue is the @StartDate and @EndDate parameters. I'm getting the following:

ERROR [HY000] [DataDirect][ODBC Progress OpenEdge Wire Protocol driver][OPENEDGE]Syntax error in SQL statement at or about "@StartDate and pub.transactions.date <= @E" (10713)

I do get this pop up before the error, but unsure how to proceed with it correctly either. I've tried reading through the documentation but couldn't figure it out:

[image: Pop Up Snippet]

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Below is a snipper of the parameters values set:

[image: Parameters]

Comment: Set the parameter value to match how to want to refer to it. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4475/using-parameters-in-power-bi/#:~:text=TThe%20first%20step%20in%20creating,finally%20create%20a%20New%20Parameter.

Comment: @PatrickHurst That doesn't help me since I'm using the PowerBI Report Builder, not PowerBI Desktop. I understand the concept but unsure how to do it.

Comment: It's the same process. In your dataset you have the parameter tab/page. Set the value of the parameter to be how you're going to refer to it in the query.

Comment: Pretty sure I already am, uploading picture to show

Comment: Try ``where (pub.transactions.date >= ? and pub.transactions.date <= ?)``. My be ``named`` parameter not available for ODBC provider.

Comment: @ValNik This worked! Although it created two new parameters instead of using the ones I had already made, I renamed and deleted the originals and worked like a charm. Odd that this would only apply to ODBC though, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your dataset refer to the parameter.
[image: Dataset Query]
In the dataset parameter set the value to refer to your parameter.
[image: Dataset Parameter]

Comment: I'll add to my post a picture of this, pretty sure I'm already doing that